# Proving a subset is equal to the closure of a spanning set

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a set
\begin{equation}
\ell^2(\mathbb{N}) = \{ x:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} | \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}|x(n)|^2 < \infty\}.
\end{equation}
Define the subset $K \subset \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ as
\begin{equation}
K=\{ x \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) | x(2n+1) = x(2n) \text{ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}\}.
\end{equation}

I'm proving what the orthogonal projection is of $\ell^2$ on $K$. For this I took an orthonormal family $e_0 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, 0, ...), e_1 = (0,0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0, 0, ...), ...$. To prove that the projection is given by $p_K(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\langle x,e_k \rangle e_k$, I need to show that $K$ is the closure of span$\{e_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

It seems quite logical that this is the case, but at the same time I don't think you can take infinitely many linear combinations of the $e_i$, so I'm confused.

I'm quite lost on this, could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to verify $\text{span}\{e_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq K$. Also, $K$ is closed (check that any convergent sequence in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ taking values in $K$ converges to a point of $K$). Therefore, $\overline{\text{span}\{e_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}}\subseteq K$. To see the reverse inclusion, let $(x_n)_n\in K$. We know that $\sum_{n}|x_n|^2<\infty$, so given any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n>2N}|x_n|^2<\epsilon^2$. Then choose a sequence $(y_n)_n\in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ such that the first $2N$ terms of $(y_n)_n$ and $(x_n)_n$ are equal. For $n>2N$, set $y_n=0$. Then clearly $(y_n)_n\in \text{span}\{e_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and we have $\|(y_n)_n-(x_n)_n\|_2<\epsilon$. Thus, $(x_n)_n\in \overline{\text{span}\{e_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$. We conclude that $K\subseteq\overline{\text{span}\{e_n|n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$.